# Spring Cache a List of object with Condition getting IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache

I want to cache a List of Category when level == 0, but keeping getting IllegalArgumentException. What am I missing?

In Service class:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Cacheable(value="categories", condition="#level == 0")
public List<Category> findCategoryByLevel(int level) throws DataAccessException {
    return categoryRepository.findCategoryByLevel(level);
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'categories' for CacheableOperation[public java.util.List com.mySite.service.DidicityServiceImpl.findCategoryByLevel(int) throws org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException] caches=[categories] | key='' | condition='#level == 0' | unless=''
```

Answer (score 0):

What caching provider are you using in *Spring's Cache Abstraction*?  (I.e. ehcache, Guava, Hazelcast, etc)

It appears you are missing an explicit "*Cache*" definition and instance in your actual caching provider.  For example, when using [Pivotal GemFire](https://pivotal.io/big-data/pivotal-gemfire) as a [caching provider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#apis:spring-cache-abstraction) in [Spring's Cache Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache), you need to define a [Region](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/Region.html) (a.k.a. [Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) in the *Spring Cache Abstraction*), using your example above, like so...

```
<gfe:cache ...>

<gfe:replicated-region id="categories" persistent="false"...>
  ...
</gfe:replicated-region>
```

Spring Data GemFire goes onto [lookup](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/GemfireCacheManager.java#L75-L97) the "*Cache*" when the cached application service|repository method is invoked, and so the actual backing "*Cache*" (i.e. the GemFire Region) must exist, otherwise the *Spring Cache Abstraction* [throws an IllegalArgumentException](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/AbstractCacheResolver.java#L78-L82).

So, by way of a more explicit example, I wrote the following test...

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014-present the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.spring.cache;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.spring.cache.CachingWithConcurrentMapUsingExplicitlyNamedCachesTest.ApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

/**
 * The CachingWithConcurrentMapUsingExplicitlyNamedCachesTest class is a test suite of test cases testing the contract
 * and functionality of Spring Cache Abstraction using the ConcurrentMap-based Cache Management Strategy 
 * with explicitly named "Caches".
 * 
 * NOTE: when the Cache(s) [is|are] explicitly named using the ConcurrentMapCacheManager, then "dynamic" is disabled
 * and corresponding the named Cache in the @Cacheable annotation of the cached service method must exist 
 * (or be declared).  If no explicitly named Caches are provided to the ConcurrentMapManager constructor, then dynamic
 * is enabled and the Cache will be created at runtime, on the fly.
 *
 * @author John Blum
 * @see org.junit.Test
 * @see org.junit.runner.RunWith
 * @see org.springframework.cache.Cache
 * @see org.springframework.cache.CacheManager
 * @see org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable
 * @see org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching
 * @see org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager
 * @see org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
 * @see org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
 * @see org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
 * @see org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfiguration.class)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class CachingWithConcurrentMapUsingExplicitlyNamedCachesTest {

  @Autowired
  private NumberCategoryService numberCategoryService;

  @Test
  public void numberCategoryCaching() {
    assertThat(numberCategoryService.isCacheMiss(), is(false));

    List<NumberCategory> twoCategories = numberCategoryService.classify(2.0);

    assertThat(twoCategories, is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(twoCategories.size(), is(equalTo(3)));
    assertThat(twoCategories.containsAll(Arrays.asList(
      NumberCategory.EVEN, NumberCategory.POSITIVE, NumberCategory.WHOLE)), is(true));
    assertThat(numberCategoryService.isCacheMiss(), is(true));

    List<NumberCategory> twoCategoriesAgain = numberCategoryService.classify(2.0);

    assertThat(twoCategoriesAgain, is(sameInstance(twoCategories)));
    assertThat(numberCategoryService.isCacheMiss(), is(false));

    List<NumberCategory> negativeThreePointFiveCategories = numberCategoryService.classify(-3.5);

    assertThat(negativeThreePointFiveCategories, is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(negativeThreePointFiveCategories.size(), is(equalTo(3)));
    assertThat(negativeThreePointFiveCategories.containsAll(Arrays.asList(
      NumberCategory.ODD, NumberCategory.NEGATIVE, NumberCategory.FLOATING)), is(true));
    assertThat(numberCategoryService.isCacheMiss(), is(true));
  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableCaching
  public static class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
      //return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("Categories");
      return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("Temporary");
    }

    @Bean
    public NumberCategoryService numberCategoryService() {
      return new NumberCategoryService();
    }
  }

  @Service
  public static class NumberCategoryService {

    private volatile boolean cacheMiss;

    public boolean isCacheMiss() {
      boolean localCacheMiss = this.cacheMiss;
      this.cacheMiss = false;
      return localCacheMiss;
    }

    protected void setCacheMiss() {
      this.cacheMiss = true;
    }

    @Cacheable("Categories")
    public List<NumberCategory> classify(double number) {
      setCacheMiss();

      List<NumberCategory> categories = new ArrayList<>(3);

      categories.add(isEven(number) ? NumberCategory.EVEN : NumberCategory.ODD);
      categories.add(isPositive(number) ? NumberCategory.POSITIVE : NumberCategory.NEGATIVE);
      categories.add(isWhole(number) ? NumberCategory.WHOLE : NumberCategory.FLOATING);

      return categories;
    }

    protected boolean isEven(double number) {
      return (isWhole(number) && Math.abs(number) % 2 == 0);
    }

    protected boolean isFloating(double number) {
      return !isWhole(number);
    }

    protected boolean isNegative(double number) {
      return (number < 0);
    }

    protected boolean isOdd(double number) {
      return !isEven(number);
    }

    protected boolean isPositive(double number) {
      return (number > 0);
    }

    protected boolean isWhole(double number) {
      return (number == Math.floor(number));
    }
  }

  public enum NumberCategory {
    EVEN,
    FLOATING,
    NEGATIVE,
    ODD,
    POSITIVE,
    WHOLE
  }

}
```

This test example is currently setup to throw the **IllegalArgumentException**.  If you change this...

```
return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("Temporary");
```

To this...

```
return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("Categories");
```

Then all is well.

Hopefully this adequately illustrates the problem you are having and how to fix it.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use the key as a static hardcoded string.
Try the following "'categories'"

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Cacheable(value="'categories'", condition="#level == 0")
public List<Category> findCategoryByLevel(int level) throws DataAccessException {
    return categoryRepository.findCategoryByLevel(level);
}
```